# Rails 3: Difference between Relation.count and Relation.all.count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Moin,

i stumbled upon a inconsistency in ActiveRecord.
I tried to get all used combinations of values in two columns of a large table.
First idea:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM table
```

Imagine a rails app that organizes meals as a model and each Meal `has_many :noodles`
Each Noodle has the attributes (and hence the DB table columns) `color` and `shape`.
My goal is to get the number of all present combinations of `color` and `shape` for a single meal.

Since AR does not provide a "distinct" method i used

```
my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape")
```

and got (in the rails console stdout) a six line output of 8 Noodle objects (respectively their String representations). But:

```
>> my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").count
=> 1606
```

In fact `my_meal` contains 1606 noodles.
If i convert the the Relation to an array and get the size of it or use `.all.count` the result is correct.

So my question is, why does AR output 8 Objects but count all the DB lines?

A similar problem [seems to be mentioned here](http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2009-06/msg01823.html) but no answer is given.

Thanks and best regards,
Tim

Comment: Can you investigate what SQL is being generated and post it here? This will be stored in `log/development.log` and is usually very revealing.

Comment: To look deeper try `to_sql`: `my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").count.to_sql`.

Comment: Actually I've just tried quite same test and in my case everything works fine. Count have made its job perfect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) for pushing me in the right direction.

I digged somewhat deeper (especially in the log files) and what i found is a little bit weird.

The problem was caused by the number of selected columns. If one selects only one column and counts the result

```
my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color").count
```

ActiveRecord creates the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct color) AS count_id FROM "NOODLES" WHERE ("NOODLES".meal_id = 295)
```

In case one selects two or more columns and applies `count` to it

```
my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").count
```

ActiveRecord forgets about that select clause and creates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM "NOODLES" WHERE ("NOODLES".meal_id = 295)
```

This may be right, since (SQL's) `COUNT` allows only one or less columns as parameters. Add a `group` before the `count` and anything is fine:

```
my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").group("color, shape").count

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, color, shape AS color_shape FROM "NOODLES" WHERE ("NOODLES".meal_id = 295) GROUP BY color, shape
```

Apart from this `AS color_shape` it is exact what i expected. BUT... only it returns this:

```
>> my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").group("color, shape").count
=> {star=>309, circle=>111, spaghetti=>189, square=>194, triangle=>179, bowtie=>301, shell=>93, letter=>230}

>> my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").group("color, shape").count.class
=> ActiveSupport::OrderedHash
```

This weird return value is (apart from order which depends on the DB) identical with the result and return value of

```
my_meal.noodles.group("shape").count
```

Conclusion:
As [pointed out here](http://metautonomo.us/2010/05/11/activerecord-relation-vs-arel/) there is still a gap between relations (may they be mathematical or arel relations) and ActiveRecord::Relations.
I can see the advantages of pressing the result in the patterns of a model as often as possible (at least in the context of a Rails app).
However real relations are not the result of the *combination* of several operations but the result of the *concatenation* of those operations.
In general the chainability of ActiveRecord::Relations is a great thing but there are some design decisions i cannot follow.
If you can't depend on the assurance that each action returns a new relation to work with, it looses much of its inuitional appeal.

As for the solution of my problem, i will use the above-mentioned `group` solution and some kind of dirty workaround for the count operation:

```
my_meal.noodles.select("distinct color, shape").group("color, shape").all.count
```

This compresses the results to an acceptable minimum before pulling them out of the database and creating expensive objects just to count them. Alternatively one could use a handwritten SQL query, but why have a Rails and do not use it, huh? ;-)

Thanks for your help,
Tim