# Ruby on Rails - ActiveRecord::Relation count method is wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, mailboxer

I'm writing an application that allows users to send one another messages about an 'offer'.

I thought I'd save myself some work and use the [Mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer) gem.

I'm following a test driven development approach with RSpec. I'm writing a test that should ensure that only one `Conversation` is allowed per offer. An offer `belongs_to` two different users (the user that made the offer, and the user that received the offer).

Here is my failing test:

```
describe "after a message is sent to the same user twice" do
  before do 
    2.times { sending_user.message_user_regarding_offer!  offer, receiving_user, random_string }
  end
  specify { sending_user.mailbox.conversations.count.should == 1 }
end
```

So before the test runs a user `sending_user` sends a message to the receiving_user twice. The `message_user_regarding_offer!` looks like this:

```
def message_user_regarding_offer! offer, receiver, body
    conversation = offer.conversation
    if conversation.nil?
      self.send_message(receiver, body, offer.conversation_subject)
    else  
      self.reply_to_conversation(conversation, body)
      # I put a binding.pry here to examine in console
    end
    offer.create_activity key: PublicActivityKeys.message_received, owner: self, recipient: receiver
end
```

On the first iteration in the test (when the first message is sent) the `conversation` variable is `nil` therefore a message is sent and a conversation is created between the two users.

On the second iteration the conversation created in the first iteration is returned and the user replies to that conversation, but a new conversation isn't created.

This all works, but the test fails and I cannot understand why!

When I place a pry binding in the code in the location specified above I can examine what is going on... now riddle me this:

[image: wtf ruby]

`self.mailbox.conversations[0]` returns a `Conversation` instance

`self.mailbox.conversations[1]` returns `nil`

`self.mailbox.conversations` clearly shows a collection containing ONE object.

`self.mailbox.conversations.count` returns 2?!

What is going on there? the `count` method is incorrect and my test is failing...

What am I missing? Or is this a bug?!

**EDIT**

`offer.conversation` looks like this:

```
  def conversation
    Conversation.where({subject: conversation_subject}).last
  end
```

and `offer.conversation_subject`:

```
  def conversation_subject
    "offer-#{self.id}"
  end
```

**EDIT 2 - Showing the first and second iteration in pry**

[image: wtf ruby 2]

Also...

`Conversation.all.count` returns 1!

and:

`Conversation.all == self.mailbox.conversations` returns `true`

and

`Conversation.all.count == self.mailbox.conversations.count` returns `false`

How can that be if the arrays are equal? I don't know what's going on here, blown hours on this now. Think it's a bug?!

**EDIT 3**

From the source of the Mailboxer gem...

```
def conversations(options = {})
  conv = Conversation.participant(@messageable)

  if options[:mailbox_type].present?
    case options[:mailbox_type]
    when 'inbox'
      conv = Conversation.inbox(@messageable)
    when 'sentbox'
      conv = Conversation.sentbox(@messageable)
    when 'trash'
      conv = Conversation.trash(@messageable)
    when  'not_trash'
      conv = Conversation.not_trash(@messageable)
    end
  end

  if (options.has_key?(:read) && options[:read]==false) || (options.has_key?(:unread) && options[:unread]==true)
    conv = conv.unread(@messageable)
  end

  conv
end
```

The `reply_to_convesation` code is available here -> http://rubydoc.info/gems/mailboxer/frames.

Just can't see what I'm doing wrong! Might rework my tests to get around this. Or ditch the gem and write my own.

Comment: Is your `self.mailbox.conversations` something like `[conversation_instance, nil]`?

Comment: nope, no nil objects in there

Comment: Am I missing something? I see `2.times` but an expectation of `count == 1`.

Comment: When you execute `self.send_message(receiver, body, offer.conversation_subject)`, you don't give the `offer` instance. Thus, I suspect the conversation isn't assigned to your instance. That could explain why, when you execute for the second time `self.send_message(receiver, body, offer.conversation_subject)`, you pass a second time through `conversation.nil?`. Thus, a second conversation is created and, as explains @peter-alfvin, the `sending_user.mailbox.conversations.count` returns the number of conversations in database, which is **2**.

Comment: Thanks but it's not that. See my updated question. The first iteration definitely creates the conversation but the second does;y. I testes in pry.

Comment: Is it possible you're invoking something other than ActiveRecord's `count` method in one case or the other?

Comment: In my experience, with operations that query the database, I'll see the SQL echoed to the console, but there's nothing being echoed in this case.

Comment: I don't actually see any SQL for any opeartion unless it's in the `rails server` process. It is a DB operation though because it's returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Comment: can you show the `mailbox.conversations` method

Comment: I had a very similar problem.  The count updater goes straight to the database without changing the active record.  Using `reload` on the record containing the count fixed it.

Comment: What does `reply_to_conversation` do?  I'd love to see the code.  Is it possible it's creating another conversation in the DB?

Comment: it is because of the way `sql COUNT()` works, see the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

see this [Rails 3: Difference between Relation.count and Relation.all.count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092745/rails-3-difference-between-relation-count-and-relation-all-count)

In short Rails ignores the `select` columns (if more than one) when you apply count to the query. This is because

> SQL's COUNT allows only one or less columns as parameters.

From `Mailbox` [code](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/conversation.rb)

```
 scope :participant, lambda {|participant|
    select('DISTINCT conversations.*').
      where('notifications.type'=> Message.name).
      order("conversations.updated_at DESC").
      joins(:receipts).merge(Receipt.recipient(participant))
  }
```

`self.mailbox.conversations.count` ignores the `select('DISTINCT conversations.*')` and counts the `join` table with `receipts`, essentially counting number of `receipts` with duplicate `conversations` in it.

On the other hand, `self.mailbox.conversations.all.count` first gets the records applying the `select`, which gets unique `conversations` and then counts it.

`self.mailbox.conversations.all == self.mailbox.conversations` since both of them query the db with the select.

To solve your problem you can use `sending_user.mailbox.conversations.all.count` or `sending_user.mailbox.conversations.group('conversations.id').length`

Answer (score 3):

I have tended to use the `size` method in my code.  As per the ActiveRecord code, size will use a cached count if available and also returns the correct number when models have been created through relations and have not yet been saved.

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 228
def size
  loaded? ? @records.length : count
end
```

There is a blog on this [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100210204319/http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size).

> In Ruby, #length and #size are synonyms and both do the same thing: they tell you how many elements are in an array or hash. Technically #length is the method and #size is an alias to it.
>
> In ActiveRecord, there are several ways to find out how many records are in an association, and there are some subtle differences in how they work.
>
> post.comments.count - Determine the number of elements with an SQL COUNT query. You can also specify conditions to count only a subset of the associated elements (e.g. :conditions => {:author_name => "josh"}). If you set up a counter cache on the association, #count will return that cached value instead of executing a new query.
>
> post.comments.length - This always loads the contents of the association into memory, then returns the number of elements loaded. Note that this won't force an update if the association had been previously loaded and then new comments were created through another way (e.g. Comment.create(...) instead of post.comments.create(...)).
>
> post.comments.size - This works as a combination of the two previous options. If the collection has already been loaded, it will return its length just like calling #length. If it hasn't been loaded yet, it's like calling #count.

It is also worth mentioning to be careful if you are **not** creating models through associations, as the related model will not necessarily have those instances in its association proxy/collection.

```
# do this
mailbox.conversations.build(attrs)
# or this
mailbox.conversations << Conversation.new(attrs)
# or this
mailbox.conversations.create(attrs)
# or this
mailbox.conversations.create!(attrs)

# NOT this
Conversation.new(mailbox_id: some_id, ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this explains what's going on, but the ActiveRecord `count` method queries the database for the number of records stored. The `length` of the `Relation` could be different, as discussed in http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=6255, although in that example, the number of records in the database was *less* than the number of items in the Rails data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.mailbox.conversations.reload; self.mailbox.conversations.count
```

or perhaps

```
self.mailbox.reload; self.mailbox.conversations.count
```

or, if neither of those work, just try `reload`ing as many of the objects as possible to see if you can get it to work (`self`, `mailbox`, `conversations`, etc.).

My guess is that something is messed up between memory and the DB. This is definitely a really weird error though, might wanna put in an issue on Rails to see why this would be the case.

Comment: Damn it, I really wanted this to work but it hasn't fixed it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `mailbox.conversations` is cached after the first call. To reload it write `mailbox.conversations(true)`