# Rails Console outputting only first record of array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm playing with data in my rails console testing some relationships and it seems to be only outputting the first record of an array.

I have an variable called `c` which is an instance of the `Comparison` class in my project.

I have a relationship set up so I can call c.products and it will return me an array of all the products in that comparison which in this case is 2.

The problem is when I call:

`c.products` it returns only the first product out of the 2.

`c.products[1]` returns nil.

`y c.products` a more detailed version of the same data shows both products.

`c.products.count` returns 2.

Here is what it looks like in rails c:

```
c.products
=> [#<Product id: 1, category_id: 3, name: "Camera", description: "erererer", brand: "Canon", quantity: 3, star_rating: 4, price: 299.0, created_at: "2014-06-18 20:26:34", updated_at: "2014-06-19 06:40:34">]

c.products.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "compared_products" ON "products"."id" = "compared_products"."product_id" WHERE "compared_products"."comparison_id" = $1  [["comparison_id", 2]]
=> 2
```

and y c.products condensed it to show only up to the last product as returns a lot of data.

```
y c.products
--- &10 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
association: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation
  reflection: &1 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection
    macro: :has_many
    name: :products
    scope: 
    options:
      :through: :compared_products
    active_record: &2 !ruby/class 'Comparison'
    klass: &3 !ruby/class 'Product'
    plural_name: products
    collection: true
    automatic_inverse_of: false
    type: 
    foreign_type: products_type
    constructable: true
    source_reflection_name: :product
    class_name: Product
    chain:
    - *1
    - !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection
      macro: :has_many
      name: :compared_products
      scope: 
      options: {}
      active_record: *2
      klass: !ruby/class 'ComparedProduct'
      plural_name: compared_products
      collection: true
      automatic_inverse_of: 
      type: 
      foreign_type: compared_products_type
      constructable: true
      class_name: ComparedProduct
      foreign_key: comparison_id
      active_record_primary_key: id
    scope_chain:
    - []
    - []
  owner: !ruby/object:Comparison
    attributes:
      id: 2
      user_id: 1
      name: Jacks Electronics Comparison
      created_at: 2014-06-20 16:12:36.828154000 Z
      updated_at: 2014-06-20 16:12:36.828154000 Z
  loaded: true
  target:
  - !ruby/object:Product
    attributes:
      id: 1
      category_id: 3
      name: Camera
      description: erererer
      brand: Canon
      quantity: 3
      star_rating: 4
      price: 299.0
      created_at: 2014-06-18 20:26:34.276570000 Z
      updated_at: 2014-06-19 06:40:34.776216000 Z
```

Comment: isn't it just the logging though ? Try `c.products[1]`

Comment: c.products[1] returns nil. This is literally so weird.

Comment: better to compare `c.products.first == c.products.last`

Comment: c.products.first == c.products.last returns true. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see `c.products` didn’t trigger sql query, that means it is cached. `c.products.count` on the other hand triggers a query and tell you actual information from database. So your `c.products` possibly changed through other association or by hand directly in database. To receive actual products do `c.products.reload`, to count cached products(without sql triggering) do `c.products.size`

See detailed explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997294

Comment: Thanks a lot Rustam. Reloaded the rails console and it's returning the full array now.